# textbf in mintinline

Tags: sectioning, minted, inline

I am trying to have **bold font** in a `subsection*{}` with using `\mintinline`.

Is there anyway to accomplish that?

Here is the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\subsection*{\mintinline{python}{compare_cpu_and_memory():}} This function deals with the comparison of the solver memory usage and solver CPU time of both framework generated models.

\end{document}
```

I want to make `compare_cpu_and_memory():` bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text is already bold, but the default font does not have bold typewriter letters, so one cannot see it. With another font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{\mintinline{python}{compare_cpu_and_memory():}} This function deals with the comparison of the solver memory usage and solver CPU time of both framework generated models.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a question is this beramono changes only the subsections or all of the text font?

Comment: @oakca it changes all typewriter font, not the text font.

Comment: what you mean by all typewriter? btw I ll accept it in some mins..

Comment: @oakca typewriter font is the font used for code in which each letter is the same width as the others

Comment: If I understand correct it will change all of the mintinline s and minted parts :)

Comment: @oakca yes, theoretically one could use packages to modify only the font in the titles, but this will look horrible.

Comment: @oakca Typewriter fonts are monospaced fonts.